# SQL | Update query with left join and case condition

Tags: sql, oracle, merge, oracle11g, sql-update

```
TABLE A


ID , PER , DATE , CALC
1 , 11 , 1-Apr , 1
1 ,6, 2-Apr , 4
2 ,7 , 1-apr ,2
2 , 12 , 2-apr , 3
3 , 13 , 2-apr , 1
4 , 8 , 2-ape , 2
```

Need to write update query based on below condition

Condition for calc column is
Calc = 1 when per is more than 10% and no previous entry

Calc =2 when per is more than 5% and less than 10% and no previous entry

Calc =3 when per is increased from the last entry

Calc = 4 when per is decreased from last entry

Comment: You say "left join" in your title, but in the body of your question there is no mention of it, and you only show one table. I stopped reading, because the whole thing already doesn't make sense. Please clarify your question - if it has nothing to do with "joins" then edit your title to properly reflect your problem.

Comment: Also: I see the abbreviation for the month of April written as **Apr** in some rows, **apr** (not capitalized) in others, and **ape** in the last row. If it's hard to keep that straight, then surely writing correct SQL, especially for non-trivial problems, will be that much harder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Oracles LAG function to access the previous row ([link](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions070.htm)). The rest is a big CASE statement handling the different states.

In my example below I assume that ID and DATE column are a primary key on the demo table.
You should check the parts where NULL is used for CALC (marked by 2 question marks). This are states not defined by your description.

```
BEGIN
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'drop table table_a';
EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN NULL;
END;
/
create table table_a (
    "ID" number,
    "PER" number,
    "DATE" date,
    "CALC" number
);
/
insert into table_a 
select 1 "ID", 11 "PER", trunc(sysdate)-1 "DATE", null "CALC" from dual
union all
select 1 "ID", 6 "PER", trunc(sysdate) "DATE", null "CALC" from dual
union all
select 2 "ID", 7 "PER", trunc(sysdate)-1 "DATE", null "CALC" from dual
union all
select 2 "ID", 12 "PER", trunc(sysdate) "DATE", null "CALC" from dual
union all
select 3 "ID", 13 "PER", trunc(sysdate) "DATE", null "CALC" from dual
union all
select 4 "ID", 8 "PER", trunc(sysdate) "DATE", null "CALC" from dual
/

update table_a
set ("CALC") = (
    with tmp_prev as (
    select 
        "ID",
        "PER",
        "DATE",
        LAG("PER") OVER (PARTITION BY "ID" ORDER BY "ID","DATE") "PREV_PER"
    from table_a
    )
    select 
        case when "PREV_PER" is null 
            then
                case when "PER" > 10 then 1 
                else
                    case when "PER" > 5 and "PER" < 10 
                        then 2
                        else null -- ?? =10 or <=5
                    end
                end
            else
                case when "PER" > "PREV_PER" 
                    then 3
                    else 
                        case when "PER" < "PREV_PER"
                            then 4
                            else null -- ?? equal
                        end
                end
            end calc_new
    from tmp_prev
    where table_a."ID"=tmp_prev."ID" and table_a."DATE"=tmp_prev."DATE"
);
/

select * from table_a;
/
```

The result:

```
        ID        PER DATE           CALC
---------- ---------- -------- ----------
         1         11 02.05.20          1
         1          6 03.05.20          4
         2          7 02.05.20          2
         2         12 03.05.20          3
         3         13 03.05.20          1
         4          8 03.05.20          2
```

Comment: What if we have multiple records more than 2 for the same ID . Then we need to compare the current record with the record having the maximum date .